# ¿Cómo hacer un INSERT en un objeto ya creado en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Quiero realizar un insert en un objeto ya creado, indico como tengo la bd con la colección en la que quiero introducir un nueva asignatura:

```
db.cursos.insertOne({"nombre": "Curso 1", "descripcion": "Curso 1", "img": "../img/money.jpg", "asignaturas": [ { "nombre": "Matemáticas", "temas": [ {"nombre": "Ecuaciones", "test": [{ "nombre": "Test1", "duracion": 20, "pregunta": [{ "numero": 1, "enunciado": "Esto es un enunciado", "correcta": "correctísimo", "incorrecta": [ "esto está mal", "no", "esto está tela de mal" ] }] }]} ] }] })
```

Por si no me he explicado, quiero crear otra asignatura en este curso ya existente en la BD, no sabría si realizar un insert o un update y como se lo paso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para nosotros poder modificar una colección previamente llenada o con datos existentes nosotros usamos el método **update()**

Tu tienes los siguientes datos:

```js
let data = {
    "nombre": "Curso 1",
    "descripcion": "Curso 1", "img": "../img/money.jpg",
    "asignaturas": [
        {
            "nombre": "Matemáticas",
            "temas": [{
                "nombre": "Ecuaciones",
                "test": [{
                    "nombre": "Test1",
                    "duracion": 20, "pregunta":
                        [{
                            "numero": 1,
                            "enunciado": "Esto es un enunciado",
                            "correcta": "correctísimo",
                            "incorrecta": ["esto está mal", "no", "esto está tela de mal"]
                        }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Si queremos introducir otro dato dentro asignatura  se usa el operador **$push**.

**OJO: $push es solo para arreglos o arrays []**

La consulta quedaria de la siguiente manera:

1. Buscamos el _id a modificar
2. Le pasamos el nuevo dato como variable

```js
db.cursos.update({_id:ObjectId("5e90c6fef25b8a80636fedc4")}{$push: {"asignaturas": nuevoDato} })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte compañero, un saludo!!